# How to print all jar results into a file using bash script

Tags: java, bash, executable-jar

I've been trying to do this simple script that I wrote where it runs an executable jar file that I made. The command of the script are as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
msisdn=$1

java -cp /home/support/phuzca/Migration/PostpaidXMigration_lib/ -jar /home/support/phuzca/Migration/PostpaidXMigration.jar $msisdn /home/support/phuzca/Migration/config.properties /opt/tomcat9/webapps/axis2/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/PlanID.xml
```

The jar file works as expected and I receive the expected results:

[image]

The idea that I've been trying to figure out is how to prevent those texts from appearing when I run my script, and instead, print them in a file so it can be reviewed later. I hope you could open up some ideas for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: run your script like this migrateToPstopaidX.sh>output.log

Comment: I already tried that but those logs and exceptions still appears after I ran the script

Comment: I have added explanations and redirection of both `stderr` and `stdout` in `Unix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redirect the output to a file:

```
migrateToPstopaidX.sh > output.log
```

if you want to redirect `stderr` use this

```
  migrateToPstopaidX.sh &> output.log
```

you can use this `>>` to append the log  instead of `>`

Comment: I already tried that but those logs and exceptions still appears after I ran the script

Comment: I haven't tried this one. I'll try it right away. Thank you.

Comment: Can't believe I struggled with this for a day. It worked just like how I wanted to. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` to the output file.

```
migrateToPstopaidX.sh > output.log 2>&1
```

You can use `>>` to append instead of overwriting your file.

Bash executes the redirects from left to right as follows:

- `>`: Open output.log in overwrite mode and redirect `stdout` there.
- `2>&1`: Redirect `stderr` to "where `stdout` is currently going". In this case, that is a file opened in append mode. In other words, the &1 reuses the file descriptor which `stdout` currently uses.